# How do you remove styles from a FlowElement in TLF?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, tlf

I'm using the following code to apply padding to a InlineGraphicElement but it only seems to be applying the value and not removing it.

```
imageFloat = inlineGraphicElement.float;
newFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();

if (imageFloat==Float.LEFT || imageFloat==Float.START) {
    newFormat.paddingRight = 5;
    inlineGraphicElement.paddingRight = 5;
}
else if (imageFloat==Float.RIGHT || imageFloat==Float.END) {
    newFormat.paddingLeft = 5;
    inlineGraphicElement.paddingLeft = 5;
}
else {
    newFormat.paddingLeft = undefined;
    newFormat.paddingRight = undefined;
}

absoluteStart = inlineGraphicElement.getAbsoluteStart();
textContainerManager = richEditableText.mx_internal::textContainerManager as RichEditableTextContainerManager;
textContainerManager.applyFormatOperation(newFormat, null, null, absoluteStart, absoluteStart+1);
```

It looks like it ignores undefined values. Now I'm not sure how to reset the padding to none.

**UPDATE:**
I found the clearFormat method in the edit manager class:

```
editManager = richEditableText.textFlow.interactionManager as IEditManager;
currentFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
currentFormat.paddingLeft = 1;
currentFormat.paddingRight = 1;

editManager.clearFormat(currentFormat, null, null);
```

I'm not sure this is right though. But if it seems to work I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the clearFormat method in the edit manager class:

```
editManager = richEditableText.textFlow.interactionManager as IEditManager;
currentFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
currentFormat.paddingLeft = 1;
currentFormat.paddingRight = 1;

editManager.clearFormat(currentFormat, null, null);
```

You have to give a value to the properties that you want to be undefined. All the values in a new TextLayoutFormat object are undefined. So to remove any styles on a FlowElement, set the style to a value other than `undefined` and then call `clearFormat(myTextLayoutFormat)` passing in the object with properties you want to remove.

Comment: It seems that if the selection extends over paragraphs it doesn't remove the formatting.